# How can I convert my Bash script output to JSON and save it as “.json” file?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Here is my script:

#### Get System info

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t array <<< "$(df -h)"

var=$(echo "${array[1]}"| grep -aob '%' | grep -oE '[0-9]+')

echo "${array[3]:$var-3:4}

echo -e "Manufacturer:\t"`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_vendor`

echo -e "Product Name:\t"`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name`

echo -e "Version:\t"`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version`

echo -e "Serial Number:\t"`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial`

echo -e "PC Name:\t"`hostname`

echo -e "Operating System:\t"`hostnamectl | grep "Operating System" | cut -d ' ' -f5-`

echo -e "Architecture:\t"`arch`

echo -e "Processor Name:\t"`awk -F':' '/^model name/ {print $2}' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e 
              's/^[ \t]*//'`

echo -e "Memory:\t" `dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s / 1024"GB"}'`

echo -e "HDD Model:\t" `cat /sys/block/sda/device/model`

echo -e "System Main IP:\t"`hostname -I`
```

#### I want to display my output like this:

```
(
    {
    
        "Manufacturer":"Lenovo",
        "Product Name":"Thinkpad",
        "Version":"T590",
        "Serial Number":"1234567890"
    }
)
```

Comment: Yes sir, I'm a novice at bash scripting. I did this on powershell, I just piped my output to a variable then piped it  to ConvertTo-Json. I don't know how can I do this on bash, Is there a similar approach?

Answer (score 3):

### Simply use `printf` to format the output into JSON

First, you have a very blatant typo in this part of your code right here:

```
echo "${array[3]:$var-3:4}
```

Note there is no closing straight quote: `"`. Fixed it in the rewrite I did below:

But more to the point, doing something like this (using `printf`) [as suggested in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524510). Tested and works in CentOS 7.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t array <<< "$(df -h)";
var=$(echo "${array[1]}"| grep -aob '%' | grep -oE '[0-9]+');
df_output="${array[3]:$var-3:4}";

manufacturer=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_vendor);
product_name=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name);
version=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version);
serial_number=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial);
hostname=$(hostname);
operating_system=$(hostnamectl | grep "Operating System" | cut -d ' ' -f5-);
architecture=$(arch);
processor_name=$(awk -F':' '/^model name/ {print $2}' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//');
memory$(dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s / 1024"GB"}');
hdd_model=$(cat /sys/block/sda/device/model);
system_main_ip=$(hostname -I);

printf '{"manufacturer":"%s","product_name":"%s","version":"%s","serial_number":"%s","hostname":"%s","operating_system":"%s","architecture":"%s","processor_name":"%s","memory":"%s","hdd_model":"%s","system_main_ip":"%s"}' "$manufacturer" "$product_name" "$version" "$serial_number" "$hostname" "$operating_system" "$architecture" "$processor_name" "$memory" "$hdd_model" "$system_main_ip"
```

The output I get is this:

```
{"manufacturer":"Oracle Corporation","product_name":"VirtualBox","version":"VirtualBox","serial_number":"","hostname":"sandbox-centos-7","operating_system":"CentOS Linux 7 (Core)","architecture":"x86_64","processor_name":"Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1030NG7 CPU @ 1.10GHz","memory":"","hdd_model":"VBOX HARDDISK   ","system_main_ip":"10.0.2.15 192.168.56.20 "}
```

And if you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) installed, you can pipe the output of the shell script to `jq` to “pretty print” the output into some human readable format. Like let’s say your script is named `my_script.sh`, just pipe it to `jq` like this:

```
./my_script.sh | jq
```

And the output would look like this:

```
{
  "manufacturer": "Oracle Corporation",
  "product_name": "VirtualBox",
  "version": "VirtualBox",
  "serial_number": "",
  "hostname": "sandbox-centos-7",
  "operating_system": "CentOS Linux 7 (Core)",
  "architecture": "x86_64",
  "processor_name": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1030NG7 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
  "memory": "",
  "hdd_model": "VBOX HARDDISK   ",
  "system_main_ip": "10.0.2.15 192.168.56.20 "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following programs can output `json`:

[lshw](http://lshw.org/):

```bsh
lshw -json
```

[smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) v7+:

```bsh
smartctl --json --all /dev/sda
```

[lsblk](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux):

```bsh
lsblk --json
```

[lsipc](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux):

```bsh
lsipc --json
```

[sfdisk](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux)

```bsh
sfdisk --json
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of output you are running is always the same you can do something like the below.  To use awk just change the $Number to whatever column in the output you want to extract.  "Hello World" $1 equals Hello $2 equals world. As you require the use of "" symbols which are a native function in bash you may need to do something like '"' or "'"'" to print one.  The code below is not going to work without tweaking but I'm sure you can work it out from what I have said and the awk man page.

```
echo '}' >> file.temp
command | awk '{ print "text/symbols" $1, "text/symbols" $2 "text/symbols" }' >> file.temp
command | awk '{ print "text/symbols" $1, "text/symbols" $2 "text/symbols" }' >> file.temp
command | awk '{ print "text/symbols" $1, "text/symbols" $2 "text/symbols" }' >> file.temp
command | awk '{ print "text/symbols" $1, "text/symbols" $2 "text/symbols" }' >> file.temp

echo '}' >> file.temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "`jq`" installed on your system?

If yes, use it to format the output. It's really better than any solutions to output a valid JSON.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

readarray -t array <<< "$(df -h)"
declare -r var=$(echo "${array[1]}"| grep -aob '%' | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
echo "${array[3]:$var-3:4}"

declare -r manufacturer=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_vendor)
declare -r product_name=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name)
declare -r version=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version)
declare -r serial_number=$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial)
declare -r hostname=$(hostname)
declare -r operating_system=$(hostnamectl | grep "Operating System" | cut -d ' ' -f5-)
declare -r architecture=$(arch)
declare -r processor_name=$(awk -F':' '/^model name/ {print $2}' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
declare -r memory=$(dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s / 1024"GB"}')
declare -r hdd_model=$(cat /sys/block/sda/device/model)
declare -r system_main_ip=$(hostname -I)

# This is a JSON format string, not a bash string
# shellcheck disable=SC2016
declare -r JSON_FORMAT='{
    "manufacturer": $manufacturer,
    "product_name": $product_name,
    "version": $version,
    "serial_number": $serial_number,
    "hostname": $hostname,
    "operating_system": $hostname,
    "architecture": $architecture,
    "processor_name": $processor_name,
    "memory": $memory,
    "hdd_model": $hdd_model,
    "system_main_ip": $system_main_ip
    }'

declare -r JSON_CONTENT=$(jq \
        --null-input \
        --arg manufacturer     "${manufacturer}"     \
        --arg product_name     "${product_name}"     \
        --arg version          "${version}"          \
        --arg serial_number    "${serial_number}"    \
        --arg hostname         "${hostname}"         \
        --arg operating_system "${operating_system}" \
        --arg architecture     "${architecture}"     \
        --arg processor_name   "${processor_name}"   \
        --arg memory           "${memory}"           \
        --arg hdd_model        "${hdd_model}"        \
        --arg system_main_ip   "${system_main_ip}"   \
        "${JSON_FORMAT}" \
    )

printf "%s" "${JSON_CONTENT}"
```