# Filter strings in .txt files and format the output in a .json file

Tags: batch, windows-11

I'm trying to create a .bat script to filter strings in .txt files and formatting the output to a .json file.

My .txt files contain lines like this:

```bat
Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/c/ 
MAC: 00:1a:79:91:a6:cf 
Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm  
MAC: 00:1a:79:92:1a:b1 
Vence:May 6, 2022, 12:35 am
```

The target .json file is the file for configuring a program and the strings filtered in the desired layout would result like this:

```bat
[
  {
    "Name": "any",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/c/",
    "Mac": "00:1a:79:91:a6:cf"
  },
{
    "Name": "any2",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/c/",
    "Mac": "00:1a:79:ad:83:b1"
  }
]
```

My script.bat:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=:," %%a IN (C:\Users\dom19\Desktop\first.txt) DO (
 ECHO(
)
)>Accounts.json

TYPE Accounts.json
```

Im studied html and css only, I never did batch files and any help would be grateful thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert my Bash script output to JSON and save it as “.json” file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1635615/how-can-i-convert-my-bash-script-output-to-json-and-save-it-as-json-file)

Comment: To make and keep it simple, you will want to use https://ss64.com/ps/convertto-json.html for a starting point in Windows since you tagged `batch` I will assume you are asking about a Windows Batch script and not a Linux Bash script. You might [edit] though to add what operating system and such you are working with. Just tagging `batch` is vague for accuracy of applicable systems.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are a community of people interested in computers, not a free programming service. If you aleady have a start of a script, we might be able to help you, otherwise your question is very likely to be closed.

Comment: You have many files .txt with this strings/text, and need to separate and all files.txt concatenate in one .json file, filtering name, address, mac... so Is this?

Comment: yes it is just that

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not very knowledgeable about the layout and others for minors of the .json format, I created a bat that generates some files in the layout informed in the question and does a treatment to get the strings formatted for the expected output (or what I understood when any less)..

- This is my bat that first creates the same files as yours and then processes/returns the json..

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cd /d "%~dp0" & >.\Target.json echo[[

>.\File_01.txt ^
    (
     echo\Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/a/
     echo\MAC: 00:1a:79:91:a6:cf
     echo\Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
     echo\MAC: 00:1a:79:92:1a:b1
     echo\Vence:May 6, 2022, 12:35 am
    )
>.\File_02.txt ^
    (
     echo\Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/b/
     echo\MAC: 0a:1a:79:91:a6:cf
     echo\Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
     echo\MAC: 0b:1a:79:92:1a:b1
     echo\Vence:May 7, 2022, 12:35 am
    ) 
>.\File_03.txt ^
    (
     echo\Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/c/
     echo\MAC: 0c:1a:79:91:a6:cf
     echo\Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
     echo\MAC: 0d:1a:79:92:1a:b1
     echo\Vence:May 8, 2022, 12:35 am
    ) 
>.\File_04.txt ^
    (
     echo\Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/d/
     echo\MAC: 0e:1a:79:91:a6:cf
     echo\Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
     echo\MAC: 0f:1a:79:92:1a:b1
     echo\Vence:May 9, 2022, 12:35 am
    )

set _cnt=<nul & for %%G in (.\*.txt)do <con: >>.\Target.json (
     echo\  ^{& for /f useback^tokens^=1*delims^=^":^  %%i in (
        `findstr/v "Vence" ^< "%%~G"`)do if not "!_mac!" == "" (
             echo\  ^{
             set _mac=<nul
             echo;    !_name!
             echo;    !_address!
             echo;    "%%~i": "%%~j"
           ) else if /i "%%~i" == "Server" (
             set /a "_cnt+=1+0"
             set "_n=00000!_cnt!"
             set "_address="Address": "%%~j","
             echo;    "Name": "Any_!_n:~-6!",
             echo;    !_address!
           ) else (
             set "_mac=?"
             set /a "_cnt+=1+0"
             set "_n=00000!_cnt!"
             echo;    "%%~i": "%%~j"
             set "_name="Name": "Any_!_n:~-6!","
             echo;  ^},
           )
     echo\  ^}
   )

>>.\Target.json echo;] & endlocal | type .\Target.json
```

---

You need more than one for loop to do this formatting/manipulation of lines/string and get your .json file.

My test files (name and content):

- `.\File_01.txt:`

```bat
Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/a/
MAC: 00:1a:79:91:a6:cf
Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
MAC: 00:1a:79:92:1a:b1
Vence:May 6, 2022, 12:35 am
```

- `.\File_02.txt:`

```bat
Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/b/
MAC: 0a:1a:79:91:a6:cf
Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm  
MAC: 0b:1a:79:92:1a:b1
Vence:May 7, 2022, 12:35 am
```

- `.\File_03.txt:`

```bat
Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/c/
MAC: 0c:1a:79:91:a6:cf
Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
MAC: 0d:1a:79:92:1a:b1
Vence:May 8, 2022, 12:35 am
```

- `.\File_04.txt:`

```bat
Server: http://viphome1.com:33000/d/
MAC: 0e:1a:79:91:a6:cf
Vence:July 15, 2022, 11:35 pm
MAC: 0f:1a:79:92:1a:b1
Vence:May 9, 2022, 12:35 am
```

---

- Target.json obtained content

```bat
[
  {
    "Name": "Any_000001",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/a/",
    "MAC": "00:1a:79:91:a6:cf"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Any_000002",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/a/",
    "MAC": "00:1a:79:92:1a:b1"
  }
  { 
    "Name": "Any_000003",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/b/",
    "MAC": "0a:1a:79:91:a6:cf"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Any_000004",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/b/",
    "MAC": "0b:1a:79:92:1a:b1"
  }
  { 
    "Name": "Any_000005",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/c/",
    "MAC": "0c:1a:79:91:a6:cf"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Any_000006",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/c/",
    "MAC": "0d:1a:79:92:1a:b1"
  }
  { 
    "Name": "Any_000007",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/d/",
    "MAC": "0e:1a:79:91:a6:cf"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Any_000008",
    "Address": "http://viphome1.com:33000/d/",
    "MAC": "0f:1a:79:92:1a:b1"
  }
]
```

---

- Save this code as `any_name.cmd` and try to run in the same folder you have the .txt files

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cd /d "%~dp0" & >.\Target.json echo[[

set^ _cnt=<nul& for %%G in (.\*.txt)do <con: >>.\Target.json (
     echo\  ^{& for /f useback^tokens^=1*delims^=^":^  %%i in (
        `findstr/v "Vence" ^< "%%~G"`)do if not "!_mac!" == "" (
             echo\  ^{
             set _mac=<nul
             echo;    !_name!
             echo;    !_address!
             echo;    "%%~i": "%%~j"
           ) else if /i "%%~i" == "Server" (
             set /a "_cnt+=1+0"
             set "_n=00000!_cnt!"
             set "_address="Address": "%%~j","
             echo;    "Name": "Any_!_n:~-6!",
             echo;    !_address!
           ) else (
             set "_mac=?"
             set /a "_cnt+=1+0"
             set "_n=00000!_cnt!"
             echo;    "%%~i": "%%~j"
             set "_name="Name": "Any_!_n:~-6!","
             echo;  ^},
           )
     echo\  ^}
   )

>>.\Target.json echo;] & endlocal | type .\Target.json
```